# NullableConverter for Nullable properties of WinForms component

Tags: winforms, controls, nullable, propertygrid, typeconverter

If I write a WinForms visual control and want to make one of its properties of a value type [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types), do I need to create a special type converter or editor for it to make it fully usable in the VS Property Grid?

For example, .NET Framework provides the [NullableConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.nullableconverter) class. Do I need to attach it to my nullable property via the [TypeConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.1)?

I tried to convert one of the `int` properties to `int?`, and it seems this property works fine in the Property Grid. I can specify a numeric value or clear this property to make it null again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property grid uses [TypeDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor) to gets its converter information. So for example, if you have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? NullableInteger { get; set; }
}
```

With this code:

```
// get first property's type converter
var cv = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(MyClass))[0].Converter;
```

You will get the `TypeConverter` for the `NullableInteger` property, which is already `NullableConverter`.

So, you don't have to declare it manually.